Recconnect to MobaXterm desktop environment
I'm connecting from a Windows machine to a Linux desktop environment using MobaXterm using the Remote environment option in the SSH session settings.
IT imposes that the Windows machine is rebooted every night, so I lose the connection to the Linux environment, which makes me lose my work (calculations that run for a day or two at least).
The software that I'm working with uses a GUI, so I need the desktop environment and cannot work with things like screen or tmux.
Is there a way to not close but detach from the MobaXterm Linux desktop environment and later re-attach to that same environment?

I am a huge fan of mobaxterm and x11 but what I would suggest for this specific scenario would probably be the vnc path.  I am not sure how good mobaxterm vnc protocol is,but everything else is great so why wouldn't it be?
